# Complex JSON as NSArray Datasource for a UITableView iOS

Tags: iphone, json, dictionary, nsarray

I tried almost everything before posting (google, Apple Dev Doc etc.). I hope I did not miss anything before posting..

I already built a working JSON <-> Webservice <-> iPhone login.

with the following code:

```
NSString *responseString = [[[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]autorelease];
NSDictionary *jsonDict = [responseString JSONValue];
NSString *loginResult = [jsonDict valueForKey:@"LoginResult"];
```

loginResult is the name of the employee: e.g "Henning Wenger"

The corresponding JSON looks like this:

```
{"LoginResult":"S:00000412"}
```

Now I have a more complex task which I can´t manage to figure a way through:

I´m getting the following JSON from the webservice:

```
{"GetTeamPresentStatusResult"[
{"Firstname":"Steffen","Id":"00000456","IsPresent":"true","Lastname":"Polker"},
{"Firstname":"Erich","Id":"00000455","IsPresent":"true","Lastname":"Welter"},     
{"Firstname":"Titus","Id":"00000454","IsPresent":"true","Lastname":"Sommerbeck"},      {"Firstname":"Ruediger","Id":"00000453","IsPresent":"true","Lastname":"Oelmann"},{"Firstname":"Heinz","Id":"00000452","IsPresent":"true","Lastname":"Radelfs"},{"Firstname":"Franz","Id":"00000451","IsPresent":"true","Lastname":"Wippermann"},{"Firstname":"Klaus-Dieter","Id":"00000450","IsPresent":"true","Lastname":"Just"},{"Firstname":"Alan","Id":"00000412","IsPresent":"true","Lastname":"Turing"},{"Firstname":"Konrad","Id":"00000138","IsPresent":"true","Lastname":"Zuse"},{"Firstname":"Marius","Id":"00000112","IsPresent":"true","Lastname":"Sandmann"}]}
```

My code for handling this starts with:

```
NSDictionary *jsonDict = [responseString JSONValue];
NSArray *teamStatus = [jsonDict objectForKey:@"GetTeamPresentStatusResult"];
[self BuildDataSource: nil :teamStatus];
```

teamStatus now contains 10 key/value pairs.

Here is how I tried to build up the datasource for my table:

```
- (void)BuildDataSource: (id) sender: (NSArray*)teamStatusData{

teamStatusMutableArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
teamStatusDataSection = [[NSArray alloc]initWithArray:teamStatusData];

teamStatusDictSectionOne = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:teamStatusDataSection forKey:@"OrgUnits"];
[teamStatusMutableArray addObject:teamStatusDictSectionOne];

[tblView reloadData];
}
```

I can not manage to figure out which way to go from here to get the data how I need it.

Do I need different Arrays where one contains the firstname/value and another one that contains lastname/value? If yes, how do I do that?

Here are some lines I´ve tried so far which did not have helped:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
}

// Set up the cell...
//First get the dictionary object

NSDictionary *dictionary = [teamStatusMutableArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];

NSString *testString = [dictionary valueForKey:@"Firstname"];
NSArray *testarray = [dictionary objectForKey:@"OrgUnits"];

NSString *test = [testarray JSONRepresentation];

test = [test stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"[" withString:@""];
test = [test stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"]" withString:@""];

NSDictionary *jsonDict = [test JSONValue];
}
```

What I need is to have a Datasource with the Employee Names that I can bind to a Table. From there I think I can make my way without additional help.

I´m coming from the .NET (C#) world and maybe this confuses me too much.

Thank you so much..

Henning

If you need further details please ask!

Details for SPtail:

Here is the .h file:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "RootViewController.h"
#import "EmployeeDetails.h"

@interface OrgUnitAA:NSObject {
NSString *FirstName;
NSString *Id;
NSString *IsPresent;
NSString *LastName;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *FirstName;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *Id;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *IsPresent;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *LastName;

@end

@interface TeamStatusView : UIViewController {

UITableView *tblView;
NSMutableArray *teamStatusMutableArray;
NSArray *teamStatusDataSection;
NSDictionary *teamStatusDictSectionOne;
UIViewController *EmployeeDetails;
UIViewController *RootViewController;
NSMutableData *responseData;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITableView *tblView;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray *teamStatusMutableArray;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *dummyMutableArrayTimeQuota;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray *teamStatusDataSection;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSDictionary *teamStatusDictSectionOne;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIViewController *RootViewController;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIViewController *EmployeeDetails;

- (void)GetTeamStatus: id;
- (void)BuildDataSource: id: (NSArray*)teamStatusData;
@end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I´ve found a solution.

This is the way I get to the data:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
}

// Set up the cell...

NSDictionary *dictionary = [teamStatusMutableArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
NSArray *teamStatus = [dictionary objectForKey:@"OrgUnits"];

NSEnumerator *e = [teamStatus objectEnumerator];
id object;

int i = 0;
while (object = [e  nextObject]) {

    if(i == indexPath.row)
    {
        NSString *firstname = [object valueForKey:@"Firstname"];
        NSString *lastname = [object valueForKey:@"Lastname"];
        NSString *fullname = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@%@", lastname, @", ", firstname];
        cell.textLabel.text = fullname;

        bool isPresent = [object valueForKey:@"IsPresent"];

        if(isPresent == true)
        {
            cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"GreenBall.png"];
        }
        else
        {
            cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"RedBall.png"];
        }

        break;
    }
    i++;
}

[aiActivity stopAnimating];
self.aiActivity.hidden = true;

return cell;
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Hey the array returned by the web service contains dictionaries, which is obvious.

Instead of using different arrays for each property, you can create a class which extends NSObject and convert each dictionary so that you will have the objects inside an array instead of dictionaries. In this case:

```
@interface OrgUnit:NSObject {
     NSString *FirstName;
     NSNumber *Id;
     bool IsPresent;
     NSString *LastName;
}
//And all the properties here
```

After this you can convert dictionaries into object by using

```
OrgUnit *unit = [[OrgUnit alloc] init];
[unit setValuesForKeysWithDictionary:dictionary];
```

PS: The variable names in the object should be same as that of the keys in dictionary

Comment: Hello SPatil,Thanks for your answer! I tried it and get the following error when I initialize OrgUnit *unit = [[OrgUnit alloc]init]; Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_OrgUnit", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in TeamStatusView.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386. I googled but coudnt find a solution. I´ll post the content of the .h file for you above in my question.

Comment: You have a class names OrgUnitAA so, OrgUnit will give that error, tell me if I am being dumb! Otherwise try having a different .h and .m for OrgUnit....

Answer (score 0):

Could be just a typo.

Change this:

```
teamStatusDictSectionOne = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:teamStatusDataSection forKey:@"OrgUnits"];
```

To this:

```
teamStatusDictSectionOne = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:teamStatusDataSection forKey:@"OrgUnits"];
```

The change is -dictionaryWithObjects. Plural. Obj-C is kinda finicky about that stuff.

Also, you are referencing indexPath.section when you build the individual cells. I think you should be referencing the row for the cell. The row should correlate to your array index.

```
NSInteger row = [indexPath row];
NSDictionary *dictionary = [teamStatusMutableArray objectAtIndex:row];
```

Comment: Hello Bill, I changed my code like you mentioned. After the change the array In method numberOfRowsInSection is nil: NSDictionary *dictionary = [teamStatusMutableArray objectAtIndex:section];
    NSArray *array = [dictionary objectForKey:@"OrgUnits"];
    return [array count];